# If Facebook block FB developer account how we can retrieve it and what are the reason to block account

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to FB developing integration in apps.
I need some information regarding Facebook developer account,if in any case it will block how we can retrieve it back.

And what are the reasons to block Facebook developer account for Facebook.

I had search in FB documents,google and SO also but not found any useful information.
If i get the reasons or situations in which FB will block account i will try to avoid those things.

If any one knows plz post answer it will helpful.

Comment: Why don't you ask facebook?

Comment: @moritzg  already try that but i think i can't get immediate response from them that's y i posted here if any one can help me.

Comment: Read their terms of service and policies carefully. That is what you are supposed to do anyway, so I don’t see why this needs asking here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

You might contact Facebook via email (disabled@facebook.com) and describe your situation. Once you can access again, add Administrators connected with real accounts in your App Dashboard ("Roles" tab) to prevent similar situations in the future.

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh Kumar,for the information,and what are the situations or reasons FB bloack my developer account

Comment: @YBDevi it might be helpful, facebook terms and laws for Fb Dev.
[facebook law and policy for Devlopers](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#law)